# Javascript - How to only have/remove '[]' in a string

Tags: javascript, string

```
let num = '(((185 + 223.85){} \* 15)\[\] - 543)/2';
```

This seems to be working
Output - `(((){}))`

```
num = num.replace(/\[^()^{}\]/g,'');
```

This is having no effect
Output - Same as above

```
num = num.replace(/\[ ^\[\] \]/g,'');
```

Comment: You want to remove all `[` and `]` in a string?? `myString.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "")` otherwise, if you want to remove *empty* `[]` **which you did not stated in your question** - use `myString.replace(/\[\]/g, "")`

Comment: It is not clear what you really want to happen. The title is saying one thing, the *"working Output"* another, and then your code is not even having a character class in the regex... So I am confused how you can say the first one works. What is the expected output, and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If a character class starts with `^` it will match **everything except** the characters between `[]`. So `[^()^{}]` matches everything except `()^{}`

This regex `[ ^\[\] ]` doesn't start with `^` so it will match **only** the characters between `[]`

If you want to match only `[]`, remove the space from the beginning `[^\[\]]`